# How to detect Line Debugging in on & the debugger is running?

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, jrun

We have a ColdFusion 8 application running in JRun4 on Windows Server 2003.

How do we detect (& display) whether the debugger is running with **Allow Line Debugging** enabled in CF Administrator. After detecting, we want to display a warning on the application that the debugger is running.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you planning on turning on step debugging in production? If so, this is a VERY bad idea. Step debugging should really be used on local development environments.

Comment: This is for TEST environment; other developers keep it turned on even after they finished debugging. This would be used just to display a warning & thus someone turn it off.

Comment: Running step debugging in a shared environment is not a very good idea.

Comment: I totally agree with that, but that's beyond my pay-grade, but this would still help in letting _next_ developer to shutdown the debugger.

Comment: Understood. I just couldn't NOT say anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the ColdFusion Administrator API for this. Of course you will need the security/permissions in order to use this. If you are using sandbox security, enable access to the `cf_web_root/CFIDE/adminapi` directory to use the Administrator API. Basically the Administrator API gives you programmatic access to *most of* the ColdFusion Administrator settings.

[From the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html):

> You can use the Administrator API to perform most ColdFusion Administrator tasks programmatically. The Administrator API consists of a set of ColdFusion components (CFCs) that contain methods you call to perform Administrator tasks.

The CFC for managing the debug settings is `debugging.cfc`.

Here is some **pseudo code** (this has not been tested):

```
<cfscript> 

// Instantiate the administrator.cfc 
adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");

// Call the administrator.cfc login method, passing the ColdFusion Administrator password
adminObj.login("#password#","#username#");

// Instantiate the debugging CFC
debugObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.debugging");

// Call the desired CFC method
if (debugObj.isLineDebuggerEnabled()) {

    if (debugObj.isLineDebuggerRunning()) {

        // Stop line debugger
        debugObj.stopLineDebugger();
    }

    // Disable the line debugger
    debugObj.setLineDebuggerEnabled(enabled="false");
}

</cfscript>
```

That should get you started. [Here is some documentation on the debugging.cfc and it's methods](http://www.cfexecute.com/admin-api-documentation/debugging-cfc/).

```
Manages debug settings.

hierarchy:  WEB-INF.cftags.component
            CFIDE.adminapi.base
            CFIDE.adminapi.debugging
path:   {web-root}\CFIDE\adminapi\debugging.cfc
serializable:   Yes
properties: 
methods:  addDebugEvent,
          deleteIP,
          getCurrentIP,
          getDebugProperty,
          getDebugRecordset,
          getIPList,
          getLineDebuggerPort,
          getLogProperty,
          getMaxDebuggingSessions,
          isLineDebuggerEnabled,
          isLineDebuggerRunning,
          restartLineDebugger,
          setDebugProperty,
          setIP,
          setLineDebuggerEnabled,
          setLineDebuggerPort,
          setLogProperty,
          setMaxDebuggingSessions,
          startLineDebugger,
          stopLineDebugger,
          validateIP*
inherited methods:  dump,
                    getEdition,
                    getInstallType,
                    getJRunRootDir,
                    isAdminUser,
                    RDSInvoker,
                    setJrunSN
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted